# Convert ascending merge sort to descending (C )

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, mergesort

I have a merge sort program that gives output by sorting the array elements in ascending order, but I want it to give output in descending order

```
void merge(int A[] , int mid, int low, int high){
    int B[high+1];
    int i = low, j = mid+1, k = low;
    while (i <= mid && j <= high)
    {
        if (A[i] < A[j])
        {
            B[k] = A[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            B[k] = A[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    
    while (i<=mid)
    {
        B[k] = A[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j<=high)
    {
        B[k] = A[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }

    // finally moving all ele of B to A
    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++)
    {
        A[i] = B[i];
    }
}

void mergesort(int A[], int low, int high){
    int mid;
    if (low<high)
    {
        mid = (low+high)/2 ;
        mergesort(A, low, mid);
        mergesort(A, mid+1, high);
        merge(A, mid, low, high);
    }  
}
```

My approach (didn't work):
Since array B[] is sorted in ascending order (so we copy it to array A[] at the end), So while copying elements of B to A, I tried to copy from last index of B[] to first index of A[] & so on...

```
int h = high;
    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++)
    {
        A[i] = B[h];
        h--;
    }
```

But I don't know why it didn't work.

Comment: The only change in your merge sort should be flipping the comparison in one single place.. Can you find it?

Comment: What exactly means "didn't work"? Please [edit] your question and create a [mre], i.e. a program we can compile and run with example input (if necessary) and the corresponding output and the expected output. As you compare two different versions (ascending and descending order), show both versions with the corresponding output. I suggest to  add a `main` function with hard-coded input data. You could use `#ifdef` `#else` `#endif` to implement both variants in a single source code.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is working fine you have only to change the comparision on line #6.

from:

```
if (A[i] < A[j])
```

to:

```
if (A[i] > A[j])
```